# Initial pageYOffset value on Android (is it cached?)

Tags: javascript, android

I've found small bug/feature of the Android browser.

If you scroll the page down and then reload it, the window.pageYOffset value will be not equal 0!

There is a simple example:
http://pastebin.com/bHzc5Ymi

How to reproduce:

1. Copy this code and open the page on any android device
2. If there is no scrollbar click the 'Show hidden content' link to load more text :)
3. Scroll browser's window down
4. Click 'Reload' to relod the page

Below the heading you can see the initial value of `window.pageYOffset`. It will be > 0 on Android devices :(

Anybody know how to clear initial `pageYOffset` value on Android?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bug, this is a function to help people to read what they read before reloading. You can open page in new tab instead of reload.

Comment: I cannot open page in new tab.

On the original page where this "feature" was detected I'm using pageYOffset to center the custom popup after page reloading (page is reloaded after form sending and popup contains messages about validation errors).

Page's height is dynamically changed before reload so actual offset is 0 but the pageYOffset has other value.

Comment: PS When I use some dummy GET parameter with random value in URL to reload page the pageYOffset still the same. Scrolling with window.scrollTo also get no results (on Android only)